# Code/library for Poisson Disk Sampling in C/C++

Tags: c++, math, random, sampling

I'm looking for a library that implements Poisson Disk Sampling in C or C++, or another one that would be easily translatable. Preferable not incredible long source, but if it is that's okay too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a clean single-file implementation in C++:

https://github.com/corporateshark/poisson-disk-generator